# Rowwise calculation of new column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My question is related to the internals of data.table, I guess:

Why is the `sample` function regarding the column as vector of size > 1, whereas the `pmin` function is working with the column as if they are (row-wise) variables?

I hope this example-code is clarifying my question:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(probs = runif(1000000), probs2 = runif(1000000))

dt[, hit := sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(1 - probs, probs))]
# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
# incorrect number of probabilities

dt[, min_prob := pmin(probs, probs2)] # working as expected

dt[, hit := sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(1 - probs, probs)), by=1:nrow(dt)] # working
```

----------------------- additional -------------------------------------

Comparison of accepted answer and method using `by=1:nrow(dt)`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(probs = runif(1000000))

set.seed(1234)
system.time(dt[, hit := sapply(probs, function(x) sample(0:1, 1, prob=c(1 - x, x)))])
set.seed(1234)
system.time(dt[, hit2 := sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(1 - probs, probs)), by=1:nrow(dt)])

all.equal(dt$hit, dt$hit2)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Both sample() and pmin() are part of base R not `data.table`. Why are they structured/designed they way the are? I guess only their authors can answer.

Comment: `pmin` takes multiple vectors and for each position returns minimum. In 1st case you gave `prob` parametar values `1-probs` and `probs` which has length of `2*nrow(dt)` which is more than 2 (number of values to sample from)

Comment: Is it good practice to do `by=1:nrow(dt)` or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the `sample` function. From the documentation of `?sample`, the `prob` argument takes:

> prob: a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.

Since you have two possible values `c(0, 1)`, you need `prob` to be a vector of length 2.

But when you call `prob = c(1 - probs, probs)` inside your `data.table` call, it's the equivalent of calling `prob = c(1 -df$probs, df$probs)` which is a vector of length 2000000, and not of length 2 like you need.

A solution would be to use `sapply`:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(probs = runif(5), probs2 = runif(5))
dt[, hit := sapply(probs, function(x) sample(0:1, 1, prob=c(1 - x, x)))]
dt
#>        probs     probs2 hit
#> 1: 0.1196779 0.46539006   0
#> 2: 0.9896483 0.31307527   1
#> 3: 0.4169862 0.08778795   0
#> 4: 0.9456939 0.09123848   1
#> 5: 0.5033147 0.27397908   0
```

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer.  If someone is interested, I added a addition to my question with a small benchmark, not very informative, but what remains: is `by=1:nrow(dt)` good advised?

Comment: Using your `by=1:nrow(dt)` construction seems like a valid alternative. Here's a related question with a good answer which discusses some alternatives with loops and has benchmarks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667335/row-operations-in-data-table-using-by-i