# Preferred performant procedure for R data.table row-wise operations?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, rowwise

Does the following code represent the preferred procedure for traversing the rows of an R `data.table` and passing the values found at each row to a function? Or is there a more performant way to do this?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2)
n <- 100
b <- c(0.5, 1.5, -1)
phi <- 0.8
X <- cbind(1, matrix(rnorm(n*2, 0, 1), ncol = 2))
y <- X %*% matrix(b, ncol = 1) + rnorm(n, 0, phi)
d <- data.table(y, X)
setnames(d, c("y", "x0", "x1", "x2"))

logpost <- function(d, b1, b2, b3, phi, mub = 1, taub = 10, a = 0.5, z = 0.7){
    N <- nrow(d)
    mu <- b1 + b2 * d$x1 + b3 * d$x2
    lp <- -N * log(phi) -
        (1/(2*phi^2)) * sum( (d$y-mu)^2  ) -
        (1/(2*taub^2))*( (b1-mub)^2 + (b2-mub)^2 + (b3-mub)^2 ) -
        (a+1)*log(phi) - (z/phi)
    lp
}

nn <- 21
grid <- data.table(
expand.grid(b1 = seq(0, 1, len = nn),
    b2 = seq(1, 2, len = nn),
    b3 = seq(-1.5, -0.5, len = nn),
    phi = seq(0.4, 1.2, len = nn)))
grid[, id := 1:.N]
setkey(grid, id)

wraplogpost <- function(dd){
    logpost(d, dd$b1, dd$b2, dd$b3, dd$phi)
}
start <- Sys.time()
grid[, lp := wraplogpost(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(grid))]
difftime(Sys.time(), start)
# Time difference of 2.081544 secs
```

**Edit:** display first few records

```
> head(grid)
b1 b2   b3 phi id        lp
1: 0.00  1 -1.5 0.4  1 -398.7618
2: 0.05  1 -1.5 0.4  2 -380.3674
3: 0.10  1 -1.5 0.4  3 -363.5356
4: 0.15  1 -1.5 0.4  4 -348.2663
5: 0.20  1 -1.5 0.4  5 -334.5595
6: 0.25  1 -1.5 0.4  6 -322.4152
```

I have tried using `set` but that approach seems inferior

```
start <- Sys.time()
grid[, lp := NA_real_]
for(i in 1:nrow(grid)){
    llpp <- wraplogpost(grid[i])
    set(grid, i, "lp", llpp)
}
difftime(Sys.time(), start)
# Time difference of 21.71291 secs
```

**Edit:** display first few records

```
> head(grid)
b1 b2   b3 phi id        lp
1: 0.00  1 -1.5 0.4  1 -398.7618
2: 0.05  1 -1.5 0.4  2 -380.3674
3: 0.10  1 -1.5 0.4  3 -363.5356
4: 0.15  1 -1.5 0.4  4 -348.2663
5: 0.20  1 -1.5 0.4  5 -334.5595
6: 0.25  1 -1.5 0.4  6 -322.4152
```

Suggestions or pointers to the relevant docs would be appreciated.

**Edit:** per comments:

```
start <- Sys.time()
grid[, lp := wraplogpost(.SD), by = .I]
difftime(Sys.time(), start)
Warning messages:
1: In b2 * d$x1 :
    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In b3 * d$x2 :
    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In d$y - mu :
    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> difftime(Sys.time(), start)
Time difference of 0.01199317 secs
> 
> head(grid)
b1 b2   b3 phi id        lp
1: 0.00  1 -1.5 0.4  1 -620977.2
2: 0.05  1 -1.5 0.4  2 -620977.2
3: 0.10  1 -1.5 0.4  3 -620977.2
4: 0.15  1 -1.5 0.4  4 -620977.2
5: 0.20  1 -1.5 0.4  5 -620977.2
6: 0.25  1 -1.5 0.4  6 -620977.2
```

which generates the wrong values for `lp`.

**Edit** thank you for the comments and responses. I am aware that this scenario could be addressed by using alternative methods, my interest is in what the *preferred* way to do this is when using `data.table`.

**Edit** thank you for the responses again. As there have been none that address the question of how to do this explicitly with `data.table`, at the moment, I am assuming that there is no ideal way to achieve this without turning to base R.

Comment: Try `by = .I`. It's faster, see `?.I`.

Comment: Thank you. I think the help is saying that `.I` should be used for obtaining the row indices in `j` rather than as a `by` term. Also the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668187/2319695, suggests (to me at least) that `.I` should not be used in the by clause. Am I interpreting that answer incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are misinterpreting that answer. `.I` returns `seq_len(nrow(grid))` but is faster since it's a value computed by data.table. Try it.

Comment: This is generally slow because you are doing a lot of `$` extractions. Your loop would work better if your data was a matrix as opposed to a list (i.e, `data.table`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use ***matrix multiplication*** and other ***vectorization techniques*** to simplify your code, which helps you avoid running function `logpost` in a row-wise manner.

---

Below is a vectorized version of `logpost`, i.e., `logpost2`

```
logpost2 <- function(d, dd, mub = 1, taub = 10, a = 0.5, z = 0.7) {
  bmat <- as.matrix(dd[, .(b1, b2, b3)])
  xmat <- cbind(1, as.matrix(d[, .(x1, x2)]))
  phi <- dd$phi
  phi_log <- log(phi)
  lp <- -(a + nrow(d) + 1) * phi_log -
    (1 / (2 * phi^2)) * colSums((d$y - tcrossprod(xmat, bmat))^2) -
    (1 / (2 * taub^2)) * rowSums((bmat - mub)^2) - (z / phi)
  lp
}
```

and you will see

```
> start <- Sys.time()

> grid[, lp := logpost2(d, .SD)]

> difftime(Sys.time(), start)
Time difference of 0.1966231 secs
```

and

```
> head(grid)
     b1 b2   b3 phi id        lp
1: 0.00  1 -1.5 0.4  1 -398.7618
2: 0.05  1 -1.5 0.4  2 -380.3674
3: 0.10  1 -1.5 0.4  3 -363.5356
4: 0.15  1 -1.5 0.4  4 -348.2663
5: 0.20  1 -1.5 0.4  5 -334.5595
6: 0.25  1 -1.5 0.4  6 -322.4152
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a better performance (time) you could rewrite the rowwise function to a calculation with matrices.

```
start <- Sys.time()
grid_mat <- as.matrix(grid[, list(b1, b2, b3, 1)])
# function parameters
N <- nrow(d); mub = 1; taub = 10; a = 0.5; z = 0.7
d$const <- 1

# combining d$y - mu in this step already
mu_op <- matrix(c(-d$const, -d$x1, -d$x2, d$y), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
mu_mat <- grid_mat %*% mu_op
mub_mat <- (grid_mat[, c("b1", "b2", "b3")] - mub)^2
# just to save one calculation of the log
phi <- grid$phi
log_phi <- log(grid$phi)

grid$lp2 <- -N * log_phi -
  (1/(2*phi^2)) * rowSums(mu_mat^2) -
  (1/(2*taub^2))*( rowSums(mub_mat) ) -
  (a+1)*log_phi - (z/phi)
head(grid)
difftime(Sys.time(), start)
```

The first rows:

```
     b1 b2   b3 phi id        lp       lp2
1: 0.00  1 -1.5 0.4  1 -398.7618 -398.7618
2: 0.05  1 -1.5 0.4  2 -380.3674 -380.3674
3: 0.10  1 -1.5 0.4  3 -363.5356 -363.5356
4: 0.15  1 -1.5 0.4  4 -348.2663 -348.2663
5: 0.20  1 -1.5 0.4  5 -334.5595 -334.5595
6: 0.25  1 -1.5 0.4  6 -322.4152 -322.4152
```

For the timing:

```
# on your code on my pc:
Time difference of 4.390684 secs
# my code on my pc:
Time difference of 0.680476 secs
```

Comment: Great answer, you catch the point for speed up. Upvoted your answer!

Comment: Thanks, but you made that into a much more usable function with your answer.